# Replacing missing values in R with values obtained from column names if non-missing, using mutate_at

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

This is a problem I keep feeling should be simple, but has me stumped. I need to replace missing values, but I need to look up the replacement value from a different, relevant column header.

Sample data:

```
s <- data.frame(Finch=c(1, 5, NA, 2), 
            Station_1_Finch=c(NA, NA, NA, NA), 
            Station_2_Finch=c(NA, NA, 60, NA), 
            Station_3_Finch=c(NA, NA, NA, NA),
            Pigeon=c(NA, 3, 7, NA),
            Station_1_Pigeon=c(25, NA, NA, NA), 
            Station_2_Pigeon=c(NA, NA, 64, NA), 
            Station_3_Pigeon=c(NA, NA, NA, 50))
birds <- c("Finch", "Pigeon")
```

What I need to do is look up the missing values for each bird (there are over 40 in my actual data) and replace each missing value with the Station number for that bird, from the column name -- not the corresponding value in the column. Fortunately the Station column names follow the same pattern and are easy to parse. This is my desired data:

```
  Finch Station_1_Finch Station_2_Finch Station_3_Finch Pigeon Station_1_Pigeon Station_2_Pigeon Station_3_Pigeon
1     1              NA              NA              NA      1               25               NA               NA
2     5              NA              NA              NA      3               NA               NA               NA
3     2              NA              60              NA      7               NA               64               NA
4     2              NA              NA              NA      3               NA               NA               50
```

I thought mutate_at with a custom function would be the simplest way to do it, but I can't get it to work. (This was after trying lapply and a simple for loop.) This is what I have:

```
birdcleanup <- function(b) {
  rs <- colnames(s)[grepl(pattern = deparse(names(b)[1]), colnames(s)) & 
                         grepl("^Station", colnames(s))]
  for(i in seq_along(rs)) {
    if(!is.na(s[rs[i]])) {
      v <- as.numeric(str_sub(rs[i], start = 9, end = 9))
      print(v)
    }
  }
  return(v)
}

surveytrim %>%
  mutate_at(birds, ~ if_else(is.na(.), birdcleanup(.), .))
```

I thought the map family of functions from purrr might help, but after wading through the documentation, vignettes, and similar questions here, I'm still confused. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is with `data.table`

```
col_order <- names(s)
setDT(s)
s <- melt(s, measure.vars = birds, variable.name = "bird", variable.factor = FALSE)
s[, row_id := seq_len(.N)]
s[, value := ifelse(is.na(value), match(FALSE, is.na(mget(str_subset(names(s), bird)))), value), by = row_id]
s[, row_id := NULL]
s <- dcast(s, ... ~ bird, value.var = "value")[, .SD, .SDcols = col_order]
```

but it seems that order of rows has changed:

```
   Finch Station_1_Finch Station_2_Finch Station_3_Finch Pigeon Station_1_Pigeon Station_2_Pigeon Station_3_Pigeon
1:     5              NA              NA              NA      3               NA               NA               NA
2:     2              NA              NA              NA      3               NA               NA               50
3:     1              NA              NA              NA      1               25               NA               NA
4:     2              NA              60              NA      7               NA               64               NA
```

Comment: I don't understand why this works, but it does! To be precise, I don't understand how the match & mget is picking up the correct character from the column name.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one base R way to solve this :

We can use `split.default` to split data based on bird names. We remove unwanted "Station_number" from the column name to keep only the bird name. Using `max.col` we find the index of first non-NA value in the row and replace the `NA` in bird column with that value.

```
s[] <- do.call(cbind, lapply(split.default(s, 
              sub('Station_\\d+_', '', names(s))), function(x) {
          inds <- is.na(x[[1]])
          x[inds, 1] <- max.col(!is.na(x[inds, -1]), 'first')
          x
}))

s
#  Finch Station_1_Finch Station_2_Finch Station_3_Finch Pigeon
#1     1              NA              NA              NA      1
#2     5              NA              NA              NA      3
#3     2              NA              60              NA      7
#4     2              NA              NA              NA      3

#  Station_1_Pigeon Station_2_Pigeon Station_3_Pigeon
#1               25               NA               NA
#2               NA               NA               NA
#3               NA               64               NA
#4               NA               NA               50
```